# Lebesgue versus Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

Can a Lebesgue measurable function be modified on a set of first category so as become continuous except on a set of Lebesgue measure zero?

OR

Can a Baire-measurable function be modified on a set of Lebesgue measure zero so as to become continuous except on a set of first category?

Comment: I think I've answered my own question. The answer is no, in general. Let F be a Cantor subset of [0,1] with measure 0 < p < 1. The indicator of F won't work because F is first category. Instead we "fatten" up F as follows: Choose a countable dense subset of F and put a closed interval around each of these points whose combined length is p/2. The set obtained by adjoining these intervals to F is still closed. Every point on the boundary of the resulting set is a limit point of interior points, a set of positive measure, and the interior points are of second category.

Comment: I think I've answered my own question. The answer is no, in general. Let F be a Cantor subset of [0,1] with measure 1/2. The indicator of F won't work because F is of first category. Instead we "fatten up" F as follows: Choose a countable dense subset of F and put a closed interval around each of these points whose combined length is 1/4. The set obtained by adjoining these intervals to F is still closed. Every point on the boundary of the resulting set is a limit point of interior points, a set of positive measure, and the interior points are of second category. (2nd question is the dual.)